# $wpdb ajax call for search and pagination (custom post type)

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have created a custom post "news" in Wordpress and I want to search posts and paginate them without page reload.

I.m using $wpdb class and it is now working fine but when I try to do an ajax call I don't get any results.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: parent_slug in 
    <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\website\wp-content\themes\website\includes\news\output_more-news.php</b> on line <b>14</b>

<b>Fatal error</b>:  
    Call to undefined function get_terms() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\website\wp-content\themes\website\includes\news\output_more-news.php</b> on line <b>15</b>
```

here's my ajax code:
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

```
jQuery('#news_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    var
        that = jQuery(this),
        url = "http://localhost/website/wp-content/themes/website/includes/news/output_more-news.php",
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};
        that.find('[name]').each(function(index,value){
        var
            that = jQuery(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();
            data[name]= value;
            console.log(data);
    });

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        beforeSend : function (){
            //do something like loading gif
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert("form submited");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("error");
        }

    });//ajax call

    e.preventDefault()

});
```

here's output_more-news.php

```
$search_term = "%" . strtolower($_POST['name_search'])."%";
if(!empty($_POST['archive-dropdown'])){
    $archive_selected = $_POST['archive-dropdown'];
}else{
    $archive_selected = "";
}
$taxonomy = ucfirst($parent_slug);
foreach(get_terms('news_categories') as $term){
    if($term->slug == $parent_slug){
        $term_ID = $term->term_id;
    }
}
$home_url = get_home_url();
$site_directory_url = get_template_directory_uri();
$archive_selected = $_POST['archive-dropdown'];
$archive_selected = str_replace("$home_url","",$archive_selected );
$archive_selected = str_replace("?post_type=news","",$archive_selected );
$archive_date = preg_split("/[\/]+/",$archive_selected );
$archive_month = $archive_date[2];
$archive_year = $archive_date[1];

global $wpdb;

$more_news_query =
    "
            SELECT      $wpdb->posts.ID
            FROM        $wpdb->posts
            INNER JOIN  $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
            INNER JOIN  $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
            AND         $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'news_categories'
            AND         $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN ($term_ID)  
            WHERE       $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '$search_term'
            ";
if(!empty($archive_selected)){
    $more_news_query .=
        "
            AND         month($wpdb->posts.post_date) = '$archive_month'
            AND         year($wpdb->posts.post_date) = '$archive_year' 
         ";
}
$more_news_query .=
    "
            AND         $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'news'
            AND         $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
            ORDER BY    $wpdb->posts.post_date
         ";

$count_results = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (${more_news_query}) AS combined_table";
$total = $wpdb->get_var($count_results);
$items_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
$paged = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
$offset = ( $paged * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;
$max_num_pages = ceil($total / $items_per_page);
$more_news = $wpdb->get_results( $more_news_query . " LIMIT ${offset}, ${items_per_page}" );
$prev_link = $paged - 1;
if($prev_link <= 0){
    $prev_link = 1;
}
$nextlink = $paged + 1;
if($nextlink >= $max_num_pages){
    $nextlink = $max_num_pages;
}

echo"<div class='panel-group' id='accordion'>
            <div class='panel panel-default'>
                <div class='panel-heading'>
                    <h4 class='panel-title''>
                        <a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion' href='#collapseMore'>
                            <span>More News</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion' href='#collapseMore'>
                            <i class='pull-right fa fa-plus-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>";
echo "<div id='collapseMore' class='panel-collapse collapse '>";
echo "<div class='panel-body'>";
echo "<div class='search_bar clearfix'>";
echo "<div class='col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-7'>
                <form  id='news_form' method='post' action='' class='clearfix'>
                <div class='form_fields_container col-md-7'>
                    <span class='btns cut_corner_btns news_search_label'>News</span><input placeholder='Search' type='text' name='name_search'>
                    <i class='fa fa-search' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
?>
</div>
<div class='form_fields_container select_container col-md-5'>
    <span class="btns cut_corner_btns news_search_label"><?php echo strtoupper($parent_slug);?> archives</span>
    <select name="archive-dropdown" >
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'news_categories' => $taxonomy, 'type' => 'monthly', 'format' => 'option', 'post_type'=>'news', 'show_post_count' => false ) ); ?>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<?php
echo "<div class='col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 news-pagination-container'>";
echo"<div class='news-pagination pull-right'>
                <span>Page</span>
                <a class='page-numbers current' href='$home_url/$parent_slug/news/?cpage=$paged'>$paged</a>
                <span> of</span>
                <a class='page-numbers' href='$home_url/$parent_slug/news/?cpage=$max_num_pages'>$max_num_pages </a>";
echo "<a class='prev page-numbers' href='$home_url/$parent_slug/news/?cpage=$prev_link'><i class='fa fa-angle-left' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";
echo" <a class='next page-numbers' href='$home_url/$parent_slug/news/?cpage=$nextlink'><i class='fa fa-angle-right' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";



    if(!empty($total)) :
                foreach($more_news as $news) {
                        $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                        $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($news->ID, 'thumbnail-size', true);
                        $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
                        $date = get_the_date("Y-m-d ",$news->ID);
                        $title = get_the_title($news->ID);
                        $content = get_the_content($news->ID);
                        $content = substr($content,0,30);
                        $permalink = get_the_permalink();
                        echo"<div class='col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 more_post_container'>";
                        echo"<div class='more_post_thumb col-xs-4'><img class='img-responsive' src='$thumb_url'/></div>";
                        echo"<div class='more_news_content col-xs-8'>
                            <p>$date</p>
                            <p class='color-$parent_slug '>$title</p>
                            <p class=''>$content...</p>
                            <a class='more_post_permalink' href='$permalink'>more</a>
                            </div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                }
            echo"</div>";
            echo"</div>";
        else:
            echo "no results found!";
    endif;
    echo"<div id='response'></div>";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"</div>";



?>
```

Any help will be much appriciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show your ajax code

Comment: I have just updated my previous post!

Comment: check https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Have you registered your ajax calls?

Comment: Can you show output_more-news.php code?

Comment: I have just posted the output_more_news.php 
I have tried registering my ajax call but without any success.

Comment: You are using $parent_slug without initializing it? Where is $parent_slug coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to resolve the error

Adding `require '../../../wp-load.php'`in output_more-news.php, which will manually load in WordPress corefiles, but its a bad way.

The correct way is documented [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: I can't follow the documentation tho!